# How can I use 'getch' as input for moving an object in 'tkinter'?

Tags: python, tkinter, getch

I am trying to make a replica of dodger using python. In my code, I made a window using `tkinter`. I tried to use `getch()` as a way of inputting arrow key values to make the main character move. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from msvcrt import getch
import time


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.initWindow()


    def initWindow(self):
        self.master.title('Dodger')
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.master.geometry('600x800')
        self.master.config(bg='black')

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        def clientExit():
            exit()

        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label='Exit', command=clientExit)
        file.add_command(label='Start', command=self.game)

        menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)


    def game(self):
        canvas = Canvas(self.master, width='600', height='800')
        canvas.pack()
        canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 600, 800, fill='black', outline='black')

        character = canvas.create_rectangle(270, 730, 330, 760, fill='blue', outline='red')
        left = 75
        right = 77

        time.sleep(10)
        while True:
            if ord(getch()) == left:
                canvas.move(character, -5, 0)
                canvas.update()
            elif ord(getch()) == right:
                canvas.move(character, 5, 0)
                canvas.update()


root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
app.mainloop()
```

As you can see, in the `def game(self)` function, I created a rectangle as the character. Then I used `getch()` to compare keyboard inputs; pressing the right/left arrow key will move the character respectively. However, this does not work in the window: my window freezes and it says "not responding". I am forced to close the window, thus I do not know if my code is not working or if my computer sucks. Copy and paste this into your editor and please let me know how I can fix this, if possible.

BTW, when you load the window, click file, then start.

Comment: Why not use `bind()`? I am not sure what all `getch()` can do but sending an update to a function based as a key press can be done with `bind()`.

Comment: what are the args, and how can I use `bind()`?

Comment: I would probably do something like `root.bind("<Left>", some_function)`. That said you are also using the `sleep()` method in tkinter and you cannot do this. `sleep()` will freeze the tk instance and you should convert your code to use `after()` instead.

Comment: I implemented `bind()` by doing this: `self.master.bind('<left>', canvas.move(character, -5, 0)`, but this doesn't do anything. What `getch()` does, is it returns a byte value when a key is pressed; `ord()` converts that to an integer. Therefore, would `if ord(getch()) == left: bind...` work?

Comment: You have not quite used bind correctly. Take a look at the answer I provided to see what you can do. Just like with commands in buttons you cannot pass arguments in the way you are trying to. You can use lambda or use a comma for each argument you wish to pass.

Comment: You shouldn't use `getch` with tkinter. Use the GUI, or use the command line, but don't use both.

Comment: what does the first parameter do?

Comment: @flameboi The first argument is the key being press. Yes "<Left>" tells the bind method to watch for a left arrow key press. The 2nd argument is just like the `command` argument in other widgets.

Comment: ok, that clears it up... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code to follow PEP8 a little better and corrected the `game()` method by removing the `sleep()` method and adding 2 more `methods` for controlling left and right movement.

By making sure our Canvas is a class attribute and the character is a class attribute we can interact with them from any method within the class.

I made everything into a class attribute that I thought should probably be one.

Updated to include max left and max right.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.title('Dodger')
        self.master.geometry('600x800')
        self.master.config(bg='black')
        menu = tk.Menu(self.master) 
        file = tk.Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label='Exit', command=exit)
        file.add_command(label='Start', command=self.game)
        menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        self.canvas = None
        self.character = None
        self.master.bind("<Left>", self.left_key)
        self.master.bind("<Right>", self.right_key)

    def game(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, width='600', height='800')
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 600, 800, fill='black', outline='black')
        self.character = self.canvas.create_rectangle(270, 730, 330, 760, fill='blue', outline='red')

    def left_key(self, event):
        cords = self.canvas.coords(self.character)
        if cords[0] <= 5:
            print("Max left")
        else:
            self.canvas.move(self.character, -5, 0)

    def right_key(self, event):  
        cords = self.canvas.coords(self.character)
        if cords[2] >= 595:
            print("Max Right")
        else:
            self.canvas.move(self.character, 5, 0)


root = tk.Tk()
app = Window(root).pack(fill="both", expand=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how does the `bind()` make the function react with keyboard inputs? does the command, `'<Left>', imply pressing the left arrow key?

Comment: You never use `self.left` and `self.right`. You should remove those from your answer. You also don't need to do `self.canvas.update()` in the bound functions. The update happens automatically the next time tkinter checks for events. 
 Otherwise, this is a good answer.

Comment: Hum. Thanks Bryan I didn't realize self.left/right were not being used at all. I figured they were there for some reason so I left them in.

Comment: @flameboi If my answer has solved your problem please select the check box next to my answer. This is used to indicate your issuer has been resolved.

Comment: By the way, is there a way I can put a limit it on it such that `character` does not go outside the boundaries (600 x 800)?

Comment: @flameboi I have updated the code to include a max left and max right. We can use the `coords()` method of canvas to find out the outer locations of the object.